# mysql slow SQL query on execute

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

I was wondering if there is any way to make this query faster, Query Time: 31,422s

```
SELECT
p.id_orden,
p.nombre,
pro.modelo,
GROUP_CONCAT(pa.nombre SEPARATOR ', ') AS acompanates,
GROUP_CONCAT(pa.precio SEPARATOR ', ') AS price,
ROUND(SUM(pa.precio) / 1.12 , 2) AS subtotal,
ROUND(ROUND(SUM(pa.precio) / 1.12 , 2) * 0.12 , 2) AS iva,
CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(pa.precio) / 1.12 , 2) + ROUND(ROUND(SUM(pa.precio) / 1.12 , 2) * 0.12 , 2)) as total
FROM orden p
LEFT JOIN producto_orden AS pro ON p.id_orden = pro.id_orden
LEFT JOIN acompanante_orden AS pa ON p.id_orden = pa.id_orden
GROUP BY p.id_orden
```

Results from `Explain`

```
1       SIMPLE  p       ALL                                     8155    Using temporary; Using filesort
1       SIMPLE  pro     ALL                                     8327   
1       SIMPLE  pa      ALL                                     2901
```

Comment: Well we can start with the easy one ... are there keys on all of the joined columns?  What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Also, why are doing a left join to product_orden?  Plus, there is no where clause.  Querying the whole darn database gets slower by the record.

Comment: Results from EXPLAIN: http://pastebin.com/JKap9NU4

Comment: #Dan Bracuk i join product_orden and acompanante_orden because they contain extra info for each order

Comment: @Ered . . . Your explain plan suggests that you don't have indexes on `id_orden`.  Put indexes on that column in all three tables.

Comment: @Gordon hey thanks for your help it went from Query Time: 31,422s to Query Time: 0,071s http://pastebin.com/Fmh40YgR i used:


`ALTER TABLE orden ADD INDEX id_orden_IDX (id_orden) ;  
ALTER TABLE producto_orden ADD INDEX id_orden_p_IDX (id_orden) ;
ALTER TABLE acompanante_orden ADD INDEX id_orden_a_IDX (id_orden) ;`


but in the EXPLAIN result i see it's only using the index for to table and not for the first one why?

Comment: @Ered . . . I wasn't sure which index MySQL would choose, because I don't know the statistics of your tables.  If figured if you built all three, MySQL would choose a good one and improve performance.

Comment: I didn't ask why you did a join, I asked why you did an outer join.